# CollectionView KeepScrollOffset behaviour for the end of the list

Tags: xamarin.forms, uicollectionview

I am using Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.1534 and I have a list of items being displayed by a `CollectionView`.  I have new items coming in at random intervals and the user may have scrolled the list to look at any historical item. The list needs to operate in two modes:

- Monitoring: Where new items need to show immediately when added.
- Checking: Where the user will be looking at historical items in the list.

If the list is showing the last item added when a new item is added (Monitoring mode), then the list should scroll to show the new item in full. if the user has scrolled the list to look at historical items then the list should not move when new items are added.

It is an option to add new items to the top of the list or the bottom.

If the option is set to add items to the top of the list and the `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode = KeepScrollOffset` then everything works as required.

However, there does not seem to be an equivalent setting for adding items at the bottom of the list.

I have tried different settings for `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode`, but nothing works as required, and I have also looked for ways to check if the last item added is visible in the `CollectionView` before adding the new one.  The idea then would be to use `ScrollTo` if relevant, but I cannot find any way to check `CollectionView` item visibility.

I'm not sure If I am missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated especially around ways to check `CollectionView` item visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find any way to check CollectionView item visibility.

There is a [LastVisibleItemIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemsviewscrolledeventargs.lastvisibleitemindex?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs_LastVisibleItemIndex) could check whehter item be visible, you could refer to **[this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling#control-scroll-position)**:

```
void OnCollectionViewScrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("LastVisibleItemIndex: " + e.LastVisibleItemIndex);
}
```

The Xaml code:

```
<CollectionView Scrolled="OnCollectionViewScrolled">
    ...
</CollectionView>
```